# Is the Random Monad independent between replicateM iterations?

Tags: haskell, random

I am doing some Hypothesis Tests in a card game.

To do that I implemented the game and an AI that plays the game. For the test I have to do a sampling on the space of all possibilities of arrangements of cards in my deck (the deck has 24 for cards, so there are 24! different initial states of the deck). However, the sampling should be independent in the sense that (a)after shuffling the deck each initial arrangement should have probability (1/24!) and (b)if i and i' are two initial arrangements after two shuffles of the deck the probability that the arrangement i and then the arrangement i' was the initial arrangements should be (1/24!)x(1/24!).[Note1]

So, if the *d* is my deck and *shuffleDeck*  is my function to shuffle the deck. I believe that the random monad was built in a way that Probability((suffleDeck d) == i ) = 1/24!

But my question is: is this function independent when interacting with the function replicateM? In other words, is the following true?

**P((replicateM 2 (shuffleDeck d) )== [i,i']) = P((suffleDeck d) == i ) * P((suffleDeck d) == i' )**

where P(x = X) is the probability of x be X.

The code that I use for the shuffle is given below:

```
import System.Random

shuffleDeck d = do
         seed <- newStdGen 
         return $ shuffle seed d

shuffle :: StdGen -> [Card] -> [Card]
shuffle g [] = [] 
shuffle g d  = c : shuffle g' d'
        where (c, g') = oneRandomCard g d 
              d' = d\\[c]

oneRandomCard :: StdGen -> [Card] -> (Card, StdGen)
oneRandomCard g d =((last $ take n d), g1 )
              where (n,g1) = randomR (1, length d) g
```

I see that in a first look this question seems trivial, but given the way that haskell treats randomness I thought it worths a question.

[1]Note: the distribution does not need be uniform like I said. It just have to be a known distribution so I can have a grasp of the power of the test. But in this case it should be uniform.

[2]Note: As noted in a comment the function works using only System.Random instead of Control.Monad.Random.

Comment: Nothing in your code uses things from `Control.Monad.Random` except for its reexport of `System.Random`. That makes it a bit confusing, especially when you're talking about `replicateM`, but would actually be using it in `IO` instead of `Rand`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your example only uses `replicateM` in `IO`, the question is actually slightly ill-formed. `replicateM 2 (shuffleDeck d)` has type `IO [[Card]]`. It's never going to be equal to something of type `[[Card]]`. But while that technical issue is really important when using Haskell, I'm going to ignore it to answer what I think was your underlying question.

As far as I can tell, your underlying question is whether there's a difference between the two following snippets of code:

```
decks d = replicateM 2 (shuffleDeck d)
```

and

```
decks d = do
    d1 <- shuffleDeck d
    d2 <- shuffleDeck d
    return [d1, d2]
```

If there is a difference between what the two of those do, the `Monad` instance for the type in question is broken. The monad laws combined with the definition of `replicateM` require those expressions to have the same result.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot see the type problem. Since (:t replicateM) = Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a], and (:t shuffleDeck) = [Card] -> IO [Card], we have that (:t replicateM 2 (shuffleDeck d)) = IO [[Card]]. Am I using a different replicateM?

Comment: It is really easy to see that the equation holds given your comment.

Comment: @zeh You're right about the type signature being `IO [[Card]]`. But, other than that, this is a solid answer that gets to the heart of the matter.

Comment: @zeh Whoops, missed that `shuffle` doesn't return the gen object. (I consider anything that takes a gen object and doesn't return the final one or use it infinitely to be an error, so I just assumed this did return it.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, great question. And to answer your question, yes, your equation does hold. In your code, you threaded the generator explicitly instead of using MonadRandom. When you use MonadRandom, you should find that not only does your equation hold but that the two different approaches to double shuffling actually should give you the same exact shuffled decks. (This is assuming that you seed the generator in a deterministic fashion instead of with IO). Equational reasoning and refertential transparency are powerful. Let me know if I can clarify further.